# Issue with URL re-write in Angular

Tags: php, angular, url, url-rewriting

I am working on one website to convert its existing site into Angular, **I am using Angular 4**, my client wants to keep URL in new site same as its previous site.
Previous site URL was having .php extension in URL e.g. site have agent section with agent listing and agent single page, agents are getting managed from admin it has URL like

```
www.example.com/our-realtors.php
```

and for agent detail page

```
www.example.com/jenny-blain.php
```

I am using angular default routing strategy. For first time URL is working fine and data is getting fetched but once I reload the page component is not getting loaded.

Can anyone let me know what can be the issue or how can I achieve this?

Currenty I am in development mode.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Production (or) Development Mode the page component has not  loaded after refresh.

Comment: @Vignesh are you saying that what I am asking its not possible?

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: @Phil this is already implemented. But issue is that when I am reloading the page, component is not getting loaded